# Mini-HDMI to HDMI cable adapter

Tags: video, hdmi, adapter

I have a newer nvidia video card that uses the mini-hdmi connector along with dual DVI ports.  It came with a mini-hdmi-->full size HDMI adapter, but it is this one piece clunky adapter.  This will not work with my current case as it interferes with the case when you try to use this one piece adapter.  If the adapter was a small 3 inch cable adapter, this would work just fine and would not conflict with my case.  Question is, where do I find a mini HDMI --> HDMI adapter that is not a one piece adapter?  I contacted the manufacture (MSI) and they said they only had the one style of adapter.  I have seen the EVGA cards include the adapter I am talking about, so I know they exist.  I am having trouble finding one online though.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure..  this is mini HDMI and not mini displayport, correct?

You don't have to buy an adapter.  They actually sell mini HDMI cables (mini HDMI on one end, full size HDMI on the other) .. check ebay - you can find them cheap.

Comment: Yes, this is mini-HDMI.  Any idea what the longest length available is?